# Guardar un valor numerico separado por comas en una variable sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

Saludos a todos, quisiera saber si alguno de ustedes han utilizado algún metodo que permita guardar una cadena numérica separada por comas y de ahí guardarla en una variable para después utilizarse.

En el ejemplo siguiente, lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que la variable @UnitsysId almacene toda la cadena de los numeros, cada que separación de comas corresponde al id de cada catalogo de un registro. Al momento de filtrarlos por la variable no me la acepta. ¿Alguien sabe como hacer esto y si es posible hacerlo?

```
declare @unitsysid varchar(max)
set @unitsysid = 120529170,120520370,120536170,120535270,120524770,159254670,108139370,104620670,165324570

select  v.UnitSysId, v.VehicleId as VehicleFleetVehicleID,a.VehicleId as VehicleSVRVehicleId,p.SharedVehicleId as VehicleSharedId
    from Fleet..Vehicles v with  (nolock)
        join AVLStatic..Vehicles  a with  (nolock) on v.UnitSysId=a.RMUId
        join PAI..PAIVehicleShared p with  (nolock) on v.VehicleId=p.FleetVehicleId
where v.UnitSysId in (@unitsysid) order by v.VehicleId asc
```

Cabe mencionar que si ingreso los datos directamente en la consulta en lugar de la variable, me los muestra sin ningún problema.

```
select  v.UnitSysId, v.VehicleId as VehicleFleetVehicleID,a.VehicleId as VehicleSVRVehicleId,p.SharedVehicleId as VehicleSharedId
    from Fleet..Vehicles v with  (nolock)
        join AVLStatic..Vehicles  a with  (nolock) on v.UnitSysId=a.RMUId
        join PAI..PAIVehicleShared p with  (nolock) on v.VehicleId=p.FleetVehicleId
where v.UnitSysId in (120529170,120520370,120536170,120535270,120524770,159254670,108139370,104620670,165324570) order by v.VehicleId asc




UnitSysId   VehicleFleetVehicleID   VehicleSVRVehicleId VehicleSharedId
120520370       24803                     35588              20119
120536170       24809                     35594              20125
120535270       24811                     35596              20127
120524770       24813                     35598              20129
120529170       24818                     35603              20134
159254670       31608                     41933              27116
104620670       50398                     44270              29828
108139370       50413                     44285              29844
165324570       52041                     45819              33485
```

Gracias.

Comment: No es imposible, pero es muy incómodo hacerlo. Necesitarías una función que haga el split de los diferentes valores para poder pasarselos al `IN`. Se discute de diferentes opciones [aquí](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings). Otra alternativa, que no recomiendo, es usar SQL dinámico. Si estuvieras usando SQL Server 2016, entonces habría una solución mas sencilla.  Nota aparte, el uso de `with (nolock)` no es buena práctica. Para mas detalles, puedes ver [aquí](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/).

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Como bien dice @sstan, las formas de resolver tu consulta serían: 1. una función que desagregue la lista y devuelva por ejemplo una tabla que puedas usar en un `inner join`, 2. o bien construir una sentencia dinámica y ejecutarla mediante `sp_executesql`.

Sin embargo, otra solución algo más parecida a lo que esperas podría ser:

```
declare @unitsysid varchar(max)
set @unitsysid = '120529170,120520370,120536170,120535270,120524770,159254670,108139370,104620670,165324570'
set @unitsysid = ',' + @unitsysid + ','


select  v.UnitSysId, v.VehicleId as VehicleFleetVehicleID,a.VehicleId as VehicleSVRVehicleId,p.SharedVehicleId as VehicleSharedId
    from Fleet..Vehicles v with  (nolock)
        join AVLStatic..Vehicles  a with  (nolock) on v.UnitSysId=a.RMUId
        join PAI..PAIVehicleShared p with  (nolock) on v.VehicleId=p.FleetVehicleId
    where CHARINDEX(',' + v.UnitSysId + ',', @unitsysid) > 0
    order by v.VehicleId asc
```

Lo que hacemos es en primer lugar asegurarnos que set cada ID este encerrado entre comas `@unitsysid = ',' + @unitsysid + ','` esto es importante por que luego lo que hacemos es ver si cada `v.UnitSysId` se encuentra en la cadena de id's `@unitsysid`. Al tener los datos "encerrados" entre dos caracteres específicos, evitamos problemas de valores incluidos en otros, por ejemplo el `id` `123` estaría incluido en `234123`, en cambio, buscando `,123,` no habría ambigüedad. No creo que sea una solución muy performante, en ese sentido creo que las ideas mencionadas anteriormente son mejores, pero al menos esta forma se parece un poco más a lo que intentas.

**Aclaración**: Si `UnitSysId` es numérico deberías agregar un `CONVERT`, por ejemplo: `CHARINDEX(',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,v.UnitSysId) + ',', @unitsysid)`

Comment: Una solución muy original. Gracias por el aporte. Pero en efecto, en cuanto al rendimiento, si hubiera un índice definido en la columna `UnitSysId`, esta consulta no podría usarla.